# Conditional TabItem styling

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

How can I set the first `TabItem` inside a `TabControl` with a custom style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        ...
```

What I'm trying to archive is to get the first `TabItem` with a left margin, and the others with margin = 0.

To illustrate what I'm trying to do:

How the tab control looks now:
[image]

How it should look (space before the first TabItem):
[image]

A different approach with the same results is also useful.

Comment: you need to styling the `TabControl` not the `TabItem`

Answer (score 1):

What you could do to achieve this is simply add an invisible, empty TabItem at first position:

```
 <TabItem Visibility="Hidden"/>
```

`Hidden` will cause that the tab control is not shown, but space is anyway reserved for it, so it turns out to look like something like that:
[image]

The space can be simply enlarged by choosing a `Header`for the `TabItem` with the appropriate amount of characters

Alternatively you can simply add some margin to the first `TabItem` itself

```
 <TabItem Header="TabItem1" Margin="5,0,0,0">
```

but that might result in that the Name of TabItem1 is cut off at the right side

Comment: thanks for the idea, I have a problem that all my TabItems are using MVVM, so I cant directly change the visual settings... Is there a way to do it on the style for the first TabItem (something like the css selector ::first)